# How can you change the user icon in sddm

Tags: kde5, sddm

I want sddm to display the user icon from ~/.face.icon (~/.face) like the kickoff application launcher does and not just the generic user icon.

Is that possible?

Answer (score -1):

If you want sddm to display the user icon from ~/.face, all you need to do is change the permissions of ~/.face. (Your question indicates that you have the symlink ~/.face.icon already.) Your steps would be:

```
chmod 666 ~/.face
```

or

```
chmod o+rw ~/.face
```

To see the effect immediately, you can restart sddm:

```
sudo systemctl restart sddm.service
```

I ran that last command from an ssh session while the computer was on the login screen. After changing the file permissions and restarting ssdm, the correct icon was displayed for the user.

Comment: 666 seems just as bad as 777, given that there are ways to execute files that don't have execute permission available to unprivileged users