# How do I set a picture for my user on the login screen in Lubuntu 20.04?

Tags: lubuntu, login-screen, sddm

I would like to display an image of my choice instead of the grey icon above my username on the login screen:

[image: sddm lubuntu theme login screen]

No doubt there is a setting for this somewhere, but I have failed to find it so far.

How do I change user images in the SDDM greeter?

---

<sub>Useful for testing -- you can use [this command](https://askubuntu.com/questions/43458/how-can-i-take-a-screenshot-of-the-login-screen/1261062#1261062) to preview the login screen without logging out.</sub>

Comment: You may try this answer here https://askubuntu.com/a/1007263/26246

Comment: @jokerdino https://askubuntu.com/a/1261062/527764 :D

Comment: @user.dz Thank you for taking a look! That answer seems bad to me - there should be no need to change the permissions and their suggested permissions are bad. Also, I think that question is unclear now - why didn't it work as expected?

Comment: @Zanna, Agree it is not good to give everyone such access to list users home folder. I also hate solutions that give `sddm` user the power to do so. A common folder (like in the answers here) in `/var` is more safe. Why didn't work, I expect due to permissions are not enough, still default permission for home `~/` doesn't allow read for everyone.

Comment: @user.dz oh - well if the question makes sense and you think the answer is right to suggest changing the permissions, perhaps you could edit the answer? 644 permissions should be fine, I think? Or maybe you could post your own answer, if you feel like it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a good guide for this on https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/SDDM#Installation

> User icon (avatar) SDDM reads the user icon (a.k.a. "avatar") as a PNG
> image from either ~/.face.icon for each user, or the common location
> for all users specified by FacesDir in an SDDM configuration file. The
> configuration setting can be placed in either /etc/sddm.conf directly,
> or, better, a file under /etc/sddm.conf.d/ such as
> /etc/sddm.conf.d/avatar.conf.
>
> To use the FacesDir location option, place a PNG image for each user
> named username.face.icon at the location specified by the FacesDir key
> in the configuration file. The default location for FacesDir is
> /usr/share/sddm/faces/. You can change the default FacesDir location
> to suit your needs. Here is an example:
>
> ```
> /etc/sddm.conf.d/avatar.conf
> [Theme]
> FacesDir=/var/lib/AccountsService/icons/
> ```

I Just kept the pic I wanted in `/usr/share/sddm/faces/` with the name `<user-name>.face.icon` As per the wiki it seems only .png files are supported.

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is great! Seems we do not need to create the conf file - it works just placing the file in `/usr/share/sddm/faces/` with the correct name scheme as you wrote. I made a symlink there to a file in my home - it is not a png file, but it worked very nicely

Answer (score 5):

This answer was provided in comment first by @yfluK

I'll suggest you look up the manual, ie. https://manual.lubuntu.me/stable/3/3.1/3.1.9/sddm_configuration.html?highlight=face%20icon

> To change the picture for your user when you login simply copy the
> file you want as your user picture to in your home folder with the
> name `.face.icon` .

The file is located in ~ (your user directory)

Comment: If @yfluK wants to write an answer, and uses the manual link, I'm happy to delete this :)
The Lubuntu manual is good, I suggest trying it.

Comment: Yes, simply this works, although the image becomes pixellated and it is rotated incorrectly (I'll have to work on that). Thanks very much for the link to the manual, I'm embarrassed to admit I was unaware of it!

Comment: @guiverc No problem. +1 from my side.

Comment: For a long time it has worked to use `.face` for this purpose (also with Lubuntu), but now we need `.face.icon`. Thanks for asking @Zanna, and thanks for answering guiverc.

Comment: I've rarely used it, but if I didn't like the result of the picture I chose, I just selected another (or returned to `gimp` to *play* some more). My primary purpose in answering was just to *advertize* the Lubuntu manual... so I've succeeded; thanks Zanna.

Comment: Plese notice that it still works use `.face` for this purpose in standard Ubuntu Desktop 20.04 LTS (with Gnome). I have not tested in the other Ubuntu family flavours.

Comment: You can change it via Kubuntu/KDE's `sddm` tool too (only tested that very recently, and I was most impressed with KDE & it's tool for this function)

Answer (score 5):

```
sudo nano /etc/sddm.conf
```

Under block `[Theme]`.

```
[Theme]
EnableAvatars=true
FacesDir=/usr/share/sddm/faces
```

I named my picture `my-user-name.face.icon`, so I don't mix it with user-pictures from other users.

Comment: My `/etc/sddm.conf` did not already have that block, but adding it turned out to be unnecessary - just placing the file, or a symlink to it, at `/usr/share/sddm/faces/username.face.icon` (the suffix is necessary) worked. Thanks!

Comment: For only one user enough, nice to learn.  thanks for  feedback.